# Puppet dependency resolution ordering

Tags: puppet

I have a couple hosts which have Docker containers on them, so I've defined a class called `apps::docker` which installs Docker on the hosts:

```
class apps::docker {
  include apps::docker::repository, apps::docker::install,
    apps::docker::service

  Class["Apps::Docker::Repository"] ->
  Class["Apps::Docker::Install"] ->
  Class["Apps::Docker::Service"]

  Package["Docker"] ~> Service["Docker"]
}

class apps::docker::repository {
  apt::source { 'docker':
    location    => "http://get.docker.io/ubuntu",
    key         => "A88D21E9",
    release     => "docker",
    repos       => "main",
    include_src => false
  }
}

class apps::docker::install {
  package { 'docker':
    name   => "lxc-docker",
    ensure => present
}

class apps::docker::service {
  service { 'docker':
    provider   => 'upstart',
    enable     => true,
    ensure     => running,
    hasrestart => true,
    hasstatus  => true
  }
}
```

Pretty simple stuff, actually.

The problem is that when I try to define a class which depends on this class, the execution happens out of order and commands fail. For example, my class `profiles::shiningstar::containers` depends on `apps::docker` as defined in `profiles::shiningstar`:

```
class profiles::shiningstar {
  include apps::docker
  include profiles::shiningstar::containers

  Class["Apps::Docker"] -> Class["Profiles::Shiningstar::Containers"]
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as seen below:

```
Error: /Stage[main]/Profiles::Shiningstar::Containers::Puppetmaster::Pull/Docker::Image[rfkrocktk/puppetmaster:1.0.5]/Exec[docker pull rfkrocktk/puppetmaster:1.0.5]: Could not evaluate: Could not find command 'docker'
... (similar errors)
Notice: /Stage[main]/Apps::Docker::Repository/Apt::Source[docker]/Apt::Key[Add key: A88D21E9 from Apt::Source docker]/Apt_key[Add key: A88D21E9 from Apt::Source docker]/ensure: created
```

It's executing things completely out of order. What's wrong with my configuration and how can I specify that ALL of the dependencies of `apps::docker` must be satisfied before `profiles::shiningstar::containers`?

Comment: Is `Class["Apps::Docker::Service"] -> Class["Profiles::Shiningstar::Containers"]` an option, or do you *need* it to be `Class["Apps::Docker"]`?

Comment: It isn't strictly necessary, but i'd like to avoid it if I can. Reason being that I'd like to decouple the implementation: I want Docker installed, I'm not so interested in the details of what that looks like.

Comment: I think this might be related: https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/2533/about-puppet-class-dependencies/

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to [contain](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/function.html#contain) the inner classes instead of just including them.

```
class apps::docker {
    contain apps::docker::repository
    contain apps::docker::install
    contain apps::docker::service

    Class['apps::docker::repository']
    ->
    Class['apps::docker::install']
    ~>
    Class['apps::docker::service']
}
```

Note that it makes sense (in your case at least) to make the `::install` class as a whole `notify` all of the `::service` class. The makes you more flexible in refactoring the respective implementation of those classes.

**Edited after first comment** - don't try to put chaining arrows between `contain` statements.

Comment: Using this, I get a syntax error; it doesn't seem to like the dependency ordering arrows on the `contain` statement. When using regular `Class` directives and dependency ordering with the contain statements, things still operate out of order.

Comment: D'oh, you're right! So basically, your original code is fine, except that you should replace the `include` line in `apps::docker` to a `contain` one. Things that depend on `apps::docker` will then depend on all contained classes. - I edited my answer to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an anchor, that will ensure that all dependencies are built

```
class apps::docker {
  include apps::docker::repository, apps::docker::install,
    apps::docker::service

  Class["Apps::Docker::Repository"] ->
  Class["Apps::Docker::Install"] ->
  Class["Apps::Docker::Service"] ->
  anchor{"apps::docker":}

  Package["Docker"] ~> Service["Docker"]
}
```